# Phusion Passenger undefined symbol ap_log_error and duplicate Apache version

Tags: apache-2.2, phusion-passenger

I try to install Phusion Passenger on my CentOS 6. 
After follow installation instruction from https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/apache/install/oss/el6/

The last step is to restart Apache and I got..

`$ sudo service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [FAILED]
Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 229 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/passenger-5.1.1/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so into server: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/passenger-5.1.1/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so: undefined symbol: ap_log_error_
                                                               [FAILED]`

I verified and found that the mod_passenger.so is at the directory in the error message is exist.
Then I try to validate with following command and got something like this..

```
Final autodetection results
 * Found Apache 2.2.15!
   Information:
      apxs2          : /usr/bin/apxs
      Main executable: /usr/sbin/httpd
      Control command: /usr/sbin/apachectl
      Config file    : /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
      Error log file : unknown

   To install Phusion Passenger against this specific Apache version:
      /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/wrappers/ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/passenger-5.1.1/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module --apxs2-path='/usr/bin/apxs'

   To start, stop or restart this specific Apache version:
      /usr/sbin/apachectl start
      /usr/sbin/apachectl stop
      /usr/sbin/apachectl restart

 * Found Apache 2.2.15!
   Information:
      apxs2          : /usr/sbin/apxs
      Main executable: /usr/sbin/httpd
      Control command: /usr/sbin/apachectl
      Config file    : /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
      Error log file : unknown

   To install Phusion Passenger against this specific Apache version:
      /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/wrappers/ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/passenger-5.1.1/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module --apxs2-path='/usr/sbin/apxs'

   To start, stop or restart this specific Apache version:
      /usr/sbin/apachectl start
      /usr/sbin/apachectl stop
      /usr/sbin/apachectl restart

WARNING: You have multiple Apache installations on your system!
You are strongly recommended to read this section of the documentation:
https://www.phusionpassenger.com/install/apache/multiple_apache_installs.html
```

According to the information in the suggested link, it seem that I have problem about multiple version of Apache that I probably should force build by running command "passenger-install-apache2-module" and specify APXS2 location.

But the message above it show that there are duplicated version of Apache 2.2.15.

Any suggestion on what should I do to figure out on this, please ?

**UPDATE**
I ended up by uninstall both Apache and Phusion Passenger and then re-install them back again. Now it is running fine.

Comment: Don't create new projects on old operating systems. Start with CentOS 7.